# how to call a link/href evey x hours?

Tags: php, javascript, cron

Is there a way to make a function "PHP/JS" or a cron job to call a link/href every 12 hours for example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There might! but, what have you tried?

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie well, didn't try anything yet, that's why i posted here as i don't know how could i do this ....

Comment: You could always write a cron-job that calls a php script! :D No but seriously you dont need php or js for this, cron will do just fine

Comment: what are you running on?

Comment: I think he wants to earn the [fanatic badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/83/fanatic) :-)

Comment: Linux server, have a manual trigger of link, when you access that link will generate the rss feed, and want to make it to be accessed automatically every 12 hours to not run it manually by myself ... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a PHP script via cron job every 12 hours, you can do the following:

```
0 */12 * * * curl -s -o /dev/null http://example.com/your-php-script.php
```

Comment: Another thing to add to this is that some cron implementations actually support using the `GET` keyword in place of calling curl/wget.

Comment: hi, thanks for you answer, how can i apply it and where exactly? my server is a shared one no a dedicated or VPS...

Comment: @Jimmy Your host offers CPanel panel?

Comment: @Jimmy There are many tutorials out there, just search: [https://www.google.com/search?q=cron+job+cpanel](https://www.google.com/search?q=cron+job+cpanel)

Answer (score 0):

There are attempts at this, e.g.

- https://github.com/StefanLiebenberg/cron.js
- http://elijahr.blogspot.de/2009/03/javascript-cron.html (https://gist.github.com/4403566)

Otherwise it might be simpler to just write a traditional cron script, if possible.

Comment: so this is a JS that works like cron jobs? how can i use it exactly for calling an URL every 12 hours for example? thanks appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could do it yourself with a cron job, but there are monitoring services that
will check that a page is accessible and returns the expected data, and email or text you
if it fails.

Comment: don't want to access that URL to check if it's up or down i want it to be accessed every 12 time because is the way to populate the rss, so how can i make it exactly ?